# Stages in Yaml instead of steps?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

How can i split the below job into stages ? I want Task 2 to run only if the branch being built is master  and build is successful ? How can i do this?

```
pr: none

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
  
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - group: test-variables

steps:
  ######TASK 1#######
  - script: Build code

  ####task 2 DEPLOY CODE ########
  - script: dir
    workingDirectory: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/azure/terraform
    displayName: List contents of a folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the [source branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in a condition and combine with the condition `succeeded()`. See [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for details.

The Yaml should like this:

```
pr: none

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
  
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - group: test-variables
  isMaster: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]

stages:
- stage: BuildCode
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
      ######TASK 1#######
      - script: echo Build Code

- stage: DeployCode
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMaster, 'true'))
  dependsOn: BuildCode
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
      ####task 2 DEPLOY CODE ########
      - script: echo Deploy Code
      - script: echo $(isMaster)
```